# Option Shift word selection doesn't work in Visual Studio Code on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, bug, visual-studio-code

I can't exectly say when this started, but from some version of Visual Studio Code Option + Shift + Right Arrow/Left Arrow selection stopped working. Currently I use macOS Big Sur, but I am almost sure that this started before upgrading to Big Sur. Can anyone help me to fix this?
UPDATE: I use macOS Big Sur 11.2.2 and VS Code 1.53.2.

UPDATE 2: OPTION + SHIFT + UP/DOWN Arrow works for me, actually this shortcut adds one more cursor to other line.

UPDATE 3: This is not shortcut probelm:
[image]

Comment: Data point... works for me on Catalina 10.15.7, Code 1.54.1.

Comment: Does Option + Shift + {Up/Down} Arrow work ? I had an resemble issue for some reasons, I couldn't use left or right arrows to navigate between characters nor CMD+{C/V}... It fixed itself after a VSCode restart

Comment: OPTION + SHIFT + UP/DOWN Arrow works for me, actually this shortcut adds one more cursor to other line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! The problem was in Visual Studio keymap, which I occasionally installed and forgot about it. After deletion of this keymap, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `opt+shift+up/down` work seems to suggest that this is an keybinding issue.

Under your VSCode keybindings, check to see if the keybinding `cursorWordLeftSelect` and the corresponding right select ones are active. If they are active, check to see if any other extensions override these shortcuts (by searching for the keybind: `opt+shift+left`).

[image: Cursor word select keybinds]

Hopefully this fixes the issue.